# Find the number of ways in which the number 30 can be partitioned into three unequal parts

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways in which the number 30 can be partitioned into three unequal parts,each part being a natural number.What this number would be if equal parts are also included.

---

Let the three natural number into which 30 is partitioned are $n_1,n_2,n_3$
so $n_1+n_2+n_3=30,n_1,n_2,n_3\ge1$ 
I solved it to get $\binom{24+6-1}{6-1}$ but the answers given are $61,75.$Can someone explain how these answers were obtained.

Comment: is 0 included in their definition of natural numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a partition of $30$ into three unequal parts $p_1 > p_2 > p_3$.
Write $d_1 = p_1 - p_2$ and $d_2 = p_2 - p_3$.
Then $p_1 =  d_1 +  d_2 + p_3$ and $p_2 = d_2 + p_3$, and hence

$$30 = d_1 + 2d_2 + 3p_3.\tag{1}$$

It's easy to see that any solution to $(1)$ in positive integers corresponds uniquely to a partition of $30$ into unequal parts.
Now, counting the number of solutions ot $(1)$ in positive integers can be done easily via recursion.

---

If we do want to account for the possibility of equal parts, then our partitions satisfy $p_1\geqslant p_2\geqslant p_3$, and $p_1 = p_2 \iff d_1 = 0$ and $p_2 = p_3 \iff d_2 = 0$.
Our problem is now like $(1)$, except we allow $d_1$ and $d_2$ to be $0$.
Alternatily, with $e_1 = d_1 + 1$ and $e_2 = d_2 + 1$, we wish to solve

$$33 = e_1 + 2e_2 + 3p_3 \tag{2}$$

in the positive integers, and this is honestly not much different from what we've already done.

---

Let's count the number of solutions to equation $(1)$ in the positive integers, and hopefully you can do the same for the next bit.
I actually find it easier to count if we allow our variables to be $0$, so let's instead write $d_1 = a_1 + 1$, $d_2 = a_2 + 1$ and $p_3 = b_3 + 1$.
Hence we wish to count the solutions to

$$a_1 + 2a_2 + 3b_3 = 24$$

in the **nonnegative integers**.

By inspection, $b_3$ can take values in $\{0, 1, \dots, 8\}$, so any solution to $(1)$ corresponds to a solution (in the nonnegative integers) of exactly one of the equations below:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 24\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 21\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 18\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 15\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 12\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 9\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 6\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 3\\
a_1 + 2a_2 &=& 0\\
\end{array}
$$

Hence, all we need to do is devise a way to count the solution to $a_1 + 2a_2 = 3k$, where $a_1$, $a_2$ and $k$ are nonnegative integers.

The value of $a_2$ uniquely determines $a_1$, so we need only consider a solution to $0\leqslant a_2 \leqslant \frac32 k$ in the positive integers.
Of course, there are $\left\lfloor \frac32k\right\rfloor + 1$ such solutions.
It follows that the number of solutions is given by

$$\sum_{k=0}^{8} \left(\left\lfloor \frac32 k\right\rfloor + 1\right)= 9 + \sum_{k=0}^{8} \left\lfloor \frac32 k\right\rfloor$$

which we may yet simplify based on the parity of $k$.
For even $k$ we have that $\frac32 k$ is an integer, so we can do away with the floors.
With $k = 2j$ this yields

$$\sum_{j=0}^4 3j = 30$$

For odd $k$, writing $k = 2j+1$, we have

$$\left\lfloor \frac32 k\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{6j+3}2 \right\rfloor
=  3j + 1,$$

which yields

$$\sum_{j=0}^3 \left(3j + 1\right) = 4 + \sum_{j=0}^3 3j = 22.$$

Hence, the total number of solutions for the first part is $9+30+22 = 61$, as expected.

Comment: But how does equation (1) gives 61 as answer, I am confused

Comment: You want to count the number of solutions to equation $(1)$ in the positive integers.

Comment: ... and the extra 14 partitions that are included when equal parts are allowed come from $(1,1,28), (2,2,26), (3,3,24) \dots (14,14,2)$

Comment: @learner_avid I have expanded on how to count the number of solutions.

Comment: Fixed a small mistake in the answer, but it's good now.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we are distributing 30 identical balls into 3 identical jars.
Suppose first the jars are distinguishable.

Then, using stars and bars counting, there are $\binom{29}{2}=29\times 14$ ways of distribution. Denote a distribution by an ordered 3-tuple. Of these, one such distribution $(10, 10, 10)$ has all three jars equal, and $13\times 3$ distributions have exactly two jars equal - i.e., a permutation of $(a, a, b)$ where $a\neq b$. Why is this? Because if we set $2a+b=30$, then the $b$ value which ranges from ${2, 4, 6, ..., 28}$ determines the $a$ value, but we must ignore $a=10$. This gives 13 possible $b$ values, with 3 permutations each.

For the first part, the number of distributions for distinct jars with all different numbers of balls is $\binom{29}{2} - 1 - 3\times13.$ To get back to indistinguishable jars, we divide this through by 3!. This is valid since we now only have distributions of the form $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c,$ all distinct, and so each are overcounted exactly 6 times. This should get you 61.

For the second part, add in the 1+13 options we discounted previously, corresponding to $(10, 10, 10)$ and $(a, a, b)$ with $a\neq b$.